# azure stream analytics System.Timestamp in BST format

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

Is there anyway that I can change the Timezone with in Azure Stream analytics Job ?
Currently, it generates UTC time for `System.Timestamp`.  Looking for conversion to BST time zone instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All time handling operations in Azure Stream Analytics [are in UTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/time-management-azure-stream-analytics). It is recommended that timestamps are in UTC time zone and in ISO 8601 format. Time zone conversion is only possible through [JavaScript user define functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

Answer (score 0):

If you have datetime field you can use [TODATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to convert to preferred time zone.